# Distribution of variance for a special standardization

Tags: variance, autocorrelation, autoregressive, standardization

I am looking to find the distribution of a transformation of a variable following an autoregressive model of lag order 1. The transformation consists of standardizing the variable on a rolling basis.

Let's assume the random variable X follows an AR(1) process:

[image]

The distribution interest is that of Z which is a standardization of X using a rolling mean and a rolling standard deviation, for sake of simplicity assume 20 day rolling moments

[image]

[image]

The end goal is to find the distribution of Z. Due to the autocorrelation in X, Z ends up with a standard deviation higher than 1. I would like to know the relation between rho and the variance of Z.

I have solved for the expected value and found that it is equal to zero, as expected from the standardization, due to the expected value of Xbar is equal to the expected value of X:

[image]
[image]

What I have tried so far is using:

[image]

But that is where, I am stuck. How do I find the variance of Z?
If it is easier to use a rolling basis up to (t-1) then it is fine as well.
TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, it turns out that the solution is actually reasonably simple. The AR(1) expression is

$$x_t =\mu + \rho x_{t-1} + \epsilon_t$$

**Step 1**: We will try to find the distribution of $x_t$. If we unroll the expression for $x_t$ back in time $\infty$ steps, we get

$$x_t = \rho^{\infty}x_{-\infty}
+ \mu \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \rho^i
+ \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \rho^i \epsilon_i
$$

Under the assumption that your error is i.i.d gauusian, namely, $\epsilon \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2)$ and assuming $\rho < 1$ we can use the [geometric series sum formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression#Geometric_series) and the expression for the [sum of random normal variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_normally_distributed_random_variables) to obtain

$$x_t
\sim \mathcal{N} (\mu_0, \sigma^2_0)
= \mathcal{N} \biggl(\frac{\mu}{1-\rho}, \frac{\sigma^2}{1-\rho^2} \biggr)$$

**Step 2**: We will try to find the distribution of $\bar{x}_t$. If we unroll the expression for $x_t$ back in time $k$ steps, we get

$$x_t = \mu \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} \rho^i + \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} \rho^i \epsilon_{t-i} + \rho^k x_{t-k}$$

Now, consider the expression for the mean

$$\bar{x}_t = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} x_{t-i}$$

We will unroll each summand as many times as necessary to reach $x_{t-n}$

$$\bar{x}_t
= \frac{\mu}{n} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\sum_{i=0}^{k}\rho^i
+ \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\sum_{i=0}^{k}\rho^i \epsilon_i
+ \rho^n x_{t-n}$$

$$\bar{x}_t
= \tilde{\mu}_k + \tilde{\epsilon}_{k, t} + \rho^n x_{t-n}$$

So $\tilde{\mu}_k$ is just a number. Again, you can use formula for [sum of random normal variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_normally_distributed_random_variables) to find that $\tilde{\epsilon}_k$ is normally distributed with mean $0$ and variance

$$\tilde{\sigma}^2_k = VAR(\tilde{\epsilon}_k) = \frac{\sigma^2}{n^2} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\sum_{i=0}^{k}\rho^{2i}$$

Finally, we can calculate the the distribution for $\bar{x}_t$ to be

$$\bar{x}_t \sim \mathcal{N}(\rho^n \mu_0 + \tilde{\mu}, \rho^{2n} \sigma_0^2 + \tilde{\sigma}^2) $$

If you take this distribution, subtract its mean and divide by its sample variance, you will obtain [Student's t-distributied](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution) random variable. There is just one step remaining: the sample variance you have computed will be biased because of autoregression. An unbiased estimator must be computed for this purpose instead. The simplest solution is to compute the expected value of the variance you have proposed, find the difference to the actual variance, and thus find the correction. Maybe you can do it yourself? This post is already too long :D

Comment: Thank you for your answer Aleksejs. Thorough and well explained. I have marked it as the answer as it got me further. Perhaps I return with a question or two at a later point :)

Comment: Glad to help. Sure, feel free to ask when you have questions :)

Comment: I can see that when subtracting xbar with its own mean and standard deviation, a student t-distribution arise. But what is the case, when it is (x - xbar) / xsd? xsd  being the rolling standard deviation. Is xsd to be considered as a random variable in itself? I have done some simulations studies which gives me an approximate relation between rho and the standard deviation of Z, but I cannot match it by formula.

Comment: As I mentioned, I haven't done the final step. The final step is to find the expected value of $x_{sd}$ and see if it matches the variance of $\bar{x}$. If it does, then you get a student's distribution. If it does not, it is likely to be off by a constant multiplier. Then you can conclude that if you multiply your $Z$ by a constant, it will be student-distributed. Have you tried deriving the expected value of $x_{sd}$ by hand?

Comment: Ah yes, I miss read the last part of your answer. Thank you!

Comment: When inserting the rolledback expression for x(t) into xbar, shouldn't it be sum(rho^i*x_(t-n)) for i in 0 to k?